# How do you glue a text to a point?

Tags: graphics, labeling, interactive

I have a point {0,0} which I call A, and a point {2,1} which I call B. I want to make an image that looks like the one below.

[image]

When I resize the image I want the text labels to follow the points, so that the distances from labels to the points remain the same.

I tried with the following code

```
p0 = Point[{0, 0}];
p1 = Point[{2, 1}];
Graphics[{{p0, Text["A", Offset[{-5, -5}]]}, {p1, 
   Text["B", Offset[{160, 80}]]}}, ImageSize -> {200, 100}]
```

but as you can see, while the A label seems to be glued to p0 the B label is not glued to the p1.

[image]

So my question is how do you glue text labels to points so that when points are moved the text labels follow along.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all your `Offset` specification is strange, I'd make it `Offset[{-5, -5}, {2, 1}]`, right?

Then, you can use `GraphicsGroup` to treat it as a single item for the purpose of interactive editing:

```
p0 = Point[{0, 0}];
p1 = Point[{2, 1}];
Graphics[{
  GraphicsGroup @ {p0, Text["A", Offset[{-5, -5}, {0, 0}]]}, 
  GraphicsGroup @ {p1, Text["B", Offset[{-5, -5}, {2, 1}]]}
}, ImageSize -> {200, 100}]
```

[image]

Comment: A formulation without `Offset`: `Graphics[GraphicsGroup /@ {{p0, Text["A", {0, 0}, {1, 1}]}, {p1, 
    Text["B", {2, 1}, {-2, -1}]}}, ImageSize -> {200, 100}]`

Answer (score 4):

This is just a little remark. Using Kuba's answer above we can define a help function

```
namedPoint[pt_, ptName_, ptSize_: Medium, offset__: {-5, -5}] := 
 Module[{},
  GraphicsGroup[{{PointSize[ptSize], Point[pt]}, 
    Text[ptName, Offset[offset, pt]]}]
    ]
```

and do simple calls like

```
Graphics[{namedPoint[{0, 0}, "O"], namedPoint[{1, 1}, "A"], 
  namedPoint[{2, -1}, "B"]}, ImageSize -> 100]
```

which gives and image like this

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: The default arguments for ptSize and offset above are defined as "positional" argument using _: patterns. A better way would be to use optional arguments. Google "Setting Up Functions with Optional Arguments".

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is to use [`Callout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Callout) inside of [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot):

```
ListPlot[{Callout[p0[[1]], "A"], Callout[p1[[1]],"B"]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Callout is only available in Mathematica 11 and later.

Comment: I am not 100% it was a requirement but you can't move the label and the point together.

Answer (score 0):

Recenter your coordinate system and rescale the text coordinates

```
{{-1, -0.5}, {1, .5}} //
Graphics[{
    Point /@ #,
    Text[#1, .9 #2] &~MapThread~{{"A", "B"}, #}
    }]&
```